# How to intercept reply in Plack/Apache

Tags: apache, perl, mod-perl2, plack

Given the following handler (straight from
https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Handler::Apache2)

```
package My::ModPerl::Handler;
use Plack::Handler::Apache2;

sub get_app {
  # magic!
}

sub handler {
  my $r = shift;       # Apache2::RequestRec
  my $app = get_app(); # CODE
  #-- #(1)
  Plack::Handler::Apache2->call_app($r, $app);
  #-- #(2)
}
```

and with the `app` being a black box, is there a way to somehow retrieve
the complete response that was generated? I would like to do it in the
line marked with `#(2)` and get both the headers and the body.  Ideally,
I would do something magical in line `#(1)` and somehow force `$r` to 
store the response (and then retrieve it in `#(2)`).

Comment: You can wrap a custom Plack middleware around `$app` and pass that into the handler, make it grab the response and make that available in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap your app in a middleware that makes the PSGI response available inside your handler code.

```
package My::ModPerl::Handler;
use Plack::Handler::Apache2;

sub get_app {
    # magic!
}

sub handler {
    my $r   = shift;        # Apache2::RequestRec
    my $app = get_app();    # CODE

    my $res;                # this will hold the response

    Plack::Handler::Apache2->call_app(
        $r,
        sub {
            my $env = shift;
            $res = $app->($env);    # closes over outside variable
            return $res;
        }
    );

    # $res == [ $status, $headers, $body ]
}
```

This code closes over `$res` and assigns the response from inside the application (or rather the extra layer around it). You can then do stuff with it outside the Apache handler code in your own code.

Please note I've not run this code, but I'm pretty sure it should work.